# infowindow google maps error: can't access lexical declaration 'infowindow'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a chloropleth map of the 50 states.
Each state has a potential info window.

The catch is when a user clicks a state, an infowindow opens.  The challenge is to close it when another state is clicked.  The problem is somewhere in the code below, I can't even get the first infowindow open.

The error I get is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'infowindow' before initialization`

```
"use strict";

let map;

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 28,
      lng: -85
    }
  }); // Load GeoJSON.

  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    //"https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json"
    "maps/US_ALL_STATES.geojson"
  ); // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
  // is set to true.

  map.data.setStyle(feature => {
    let color = "blue";

    if (feature.getProperty("isColorful")) {
      color = feature.getProperty("color");
    }

    return (
      /** @type {!google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */
      ({
        fillColor: color,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeWeight: 2
      })
    );
  }); // When the user clicks, set 'isColorful', changing the color of the letters.

  map.data.addListener("click", event => {
    if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
    var content = "State:  " + event.feature.getProperty("NAME") + "\r"
    content = content + "Click <a href='county.html?state="+event.feature.getProperty("STATEFP")+"'>here</a> to Zoom in"
    const infowindow = new google.maps.infowindow({
      content: content
    });
    event.feature.setProperty("fillColor", "pink");
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
    console.log(event.feature);

  }); // When the user hovers, tempt them to click by outlining the letters.
  // Call revertStyle() to remove all overrides. This will use the style rules
  // defined in the function passed to setStyle()

  map.data.addListener("mouseover", event => {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 8,
      fillColor: "green",
      strokeColor: "pink"
    });
  });
  map.data.addListener("mouseout", event => {
    map.data.revertStyle();
  });






}
```

how do update this to make it a "one infowindow at a time" scenerio?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the variable in the persistent outside scope instead:

```
let infowindow;
map.data.addListener("click", event => {
  if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
  var content = "State:  " + event.feature.getProperty("NAME") + "\r"
  content = content + "Click <a href='county.html?state="+event.feature.getProperty("STATEFP")+"'>here</a> to Zoom in"
  infowindow = new google.maps.infowindow({
    content: content
  });
  // etc
```

Comment: the error now: Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'infowindow' before initialization

Comment: Are you sure you remove the `const infowindow` from your code? Copy my code exactly - there should not be such an error, since `infowindow` is now declared in the outer scope, not in the inner scope.

Comment: ok.  error changed: google.maps.infowindow is not a constructor

Comment: I copied it ver batim

Comment: Are you trying to use Google Maps' `InfoWindow`? If so, you need to use the right capitalization. `.InfoWindow()`. Otherwise, look at the docs for whatever defines the `infowindow` you're trying to use.